# Calculate the total in django model Device based of each DevicePart Model including qty

Tags: django

I want to calculate the total items for the device which includes quantity for each part. Not sure whether the approach I used here is going to work. Need guidance. Thanks

```
  class Device(models.Model):
        device_model = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModel, on_delete=None)
        sku = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        # total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    
       @property
        def get_cost_total(self):
            deviceparts = self.devicepart_set.all()
            total = sum([part.get_total for part in deviceparts])
            return total

        print(get_cost_total)
    
    class DevicePart(models.Model):
        device_model = models.ManyToManyField(DeviceModel)
        device = models.ManyToManyField(Device)
        part_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        part_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        service_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        unit_list_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        unit_net_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        discount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        extended_net_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    

        @property
        def get_total(self):
            total = self.extended_net_price * self.quantity
            return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing this in `Device.get_total_cost` could work, but it will not be efficient as it will pull each device part from the database storage in full and perform the calculation every time.

It will be more efficient to push the calculation to the database and just ask for the total cost with a single query. Here is how your `get_cost_total` would look like then:

```py
@property
def get_cost_total(self):
    return self.devicepart_set.annotate(
        part_price=F('extended_net_price') * F('quantity')
    ).aggregate(Sum('part_price', output_field=models.FloatField())).get('part_price__sum')
```

What this does is that it pushes the calculation of the part price (net price * quantity) inside the query that the database performs, then it adds this as "part_price" for each part.

This is similar to how you do `get_total` on each part as a model property, but this happens at the database level, so it is much more efficient.

Then an aggregation (summarization) is performed to get a total of all the 'part_price' values and the result is returned.

The procedure for aggregation and annotation is covered in the django docs below, in case you need to construct similar things:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks.....But I am getting the object reference how can I see that total value in console? (InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mysite.core.models import Device
>>> from mysite.core.models import DeviceModel
>>> from mysite.core.models import Vendor
>>> from mysite.core.models import DevicePart
>>> Device.get_cost_total
<property object at 0x7f6066f28958>

Comment: You would need to get an instance of the Device first, then check its property. Example:
```
one_device = Device.objects.get(pk=1)
print(one_device.get_cost_total)
```